# web service is not sending correct response

Tags: php, android, retrofit2

I have to get data of a user with its id and that data would be used on android usind retrofit, my php web service is

```
<?php

    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "admin", "pwd", "api");
    $id = $_POST["id"];
    $sql= "SELECT * from users WHERE id = $id ";
    $query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql)
    $result= mysqli_fetch_array($query);

    if ($result[0]>0) {
        $json = array("name" => $result[1],"last_name" => $result[2], "email" => $result[3], "password" => $result[4],
            "city" => $result[5], "address" => $result[6], "gender" => $result[7], "dob" => $result[8], "about" => $result[9], 
            "phone_number" => $result[10]); 

            header('content-type: application/json');
            echo json_encode($json);
    } 
    else {
    $json = array("result" => "null", "status" => "invalid data"); 

            header('content-type: application/json');
            echo json_encode($json);
    }


    mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

my retrofit service is

```
@FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("/getUserDetailsById.php")
    Call<User> getUserDetail(@Field("id") int id);
```

in my Activity I've

```
String uid  = mLoginPreferences.getString(Constant.USER_ID, "");
        Log.e("PREF_ID", " is " + uid);
mUserCall = mRestManager.getApiService().getUserDetail(Integer.valueOf(uid));
        mUserCall.enqueue(new Callback<User>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<User> call, Response<User> response) {
                User userDetails = response.body();

                if (userDetails.getEmail() != null){
                    Log.e("RESPONSE_ID", " is " + userDetails.getName());
                                        }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<User> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.e("DETAILS_ERROR", " message is " + t.getMessage());
            }
        });
```

at the line

```
Log.e("PREF_ID", " is " + uid);
```

I get correct id value but can not get data back from server always getting null as `respnse.body()`, want to know how can I get data of a particular user using its id.

Comment: Did you verified the status code returned? is it 200Ok?

Comment: What error are you seeing in the console ?

Comment: Tried in _Postman_ and getting __500 Internal Server error__ status

Comment: Well the issue is definitely with the server code, Try debugging it there. and check which line the code is breaking.

Comment: There's an error on line `$query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql)`, this var _$conn_ is not defined, should be _$con_!

Comment: @ArshadAli posted an answer. Hope it helps

Comment: I'm very poor in Php and that is very bad of api Dev.

Comment: let know if the change in code worked for you. @ArslanKhan

Comment: @Sanoop Yes it worked.

Comment: @ArshadAli thanks a lot Man!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the issue is you are using a different variable created, And also you missed `;` in the line

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "admin", "pwd", "api");

$query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
```

But you are querying using `$conn` which is not created , what you should be using is

```
$query = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not use `;` to complete statement that's why you are getting error.

`$query = mysqli_query($con, $sql)`

Please check above line and put `;` at last